# jquery - get 2nd column value behind active radio button

Tags: jquery

I have got a table with this kind of structure:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="databaseTable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th class="checkable">&nbsp</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <input name="line" style="float: left;" type="radio" value="2" class="radio" tabindex="1">
        </td>
        <td>121212</td>
        <td><div style="float:left;">BUBUBU</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to fetch the value BUBUBU from the table when the radio button is active. I can check when the radio button is active with:

```
$('input[name="line"]:radio:checked').val();
```

but now I want to fetch the value BUBUBU in this specific row. Does anyone know how I can fetch the value using JQuery?

Comment: You're missing a starting TD, right now your markup is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your html is not valid, it should be:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="databaseTable">
<tr class="header">
<th class="checkable">&nbsp</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td>
    <input name="line" style="float: left;" type="radio" value="2" class="radio" tabindex="1" />
    </td>
<td>121212</td>
<td><div style="float:left;">BUBUBU</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and you can get it in the click event of radio button:

```
 $('input[name="line"]').click(function () {
    alert($(this).val()); // radio button valye

    alert($(this).closest("tr").find("div").text()); // div value

});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fbQ7c/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Give that div an id like `<div id="bu">BUBUBU</div>`

and call it when you need like `$("#bu").text()` in your script

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var value = $('input[name="line"]').parent().children("td:last-child").text();
$('input[name="line"]:radio:checked').val(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` with `find()`.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name="line"]').change(function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        var self = $(this);
        var value = self.closest(".even").find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
        if(isChecked) alert(value);
    });
});
```